# How to display specific options in the menu bar just to the user with the admin role?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application which shows an admin a different menu bar than it shows the normal user. I mean if the user is the admin, he will see some options related to the settings of the system itself.
I created the menu bar as a user control (ascx) and I defind the following method in its code-behind:

```
public bool DisplayAdminOnlyMenuItems
    {
        get { return menuItem1ToHide.Visible; }
        set
        {
            menuItem1ToHide.Visible = value;
        }
    }
```

then in the in the site.master page, I put the menu bar user control and set the DisplayAdminMenuItems as false

and in the code-behind, I use the following logic:

```
if(user.username == "John"){
    MenuBar1.DisplayAdminOnlyMenuItems = true;
}
```

Everything works well and fine. Now, I got new requirements which complicates my life a little bit.
I have the three tables in my database which structure as following:

**User table:** Name, Username, Department (Username is the primary key)

**Roles table:** RoleID, RoleName (RoleID is the primary key)

**UserRole table:** UserRoleID, Username, RoleID (UserRoleID is the primary key)

I have three roles: Admin, Organizer and User
I want to display the Admin menu just for the user who has Admin role, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(user.username == "John"){
    MenuBar1.DisplayAdminOnlyMenuItems = true;
}
```

The approach you used above is not right because it is not scalable. What if there are two admins? Will you put an OR condition for each admin?

Right approach is your new requirement which is based on Role rather than users.

When you get a user check it's role and display UI based on role

```
if(user.RoleName == "Admin"){
    MenuBar1.DisplayAdminOnlyMenuItems = true;
}
```

I am assuming you can get `RoleName` if you have `UserName`

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add a new method or two to your user class to perform this logic so that you don't have references to roles spread throughout your code and so that future changes can be accommodated.

For example, if you get a request next week to add a super admin role and this role should also be able to have access to the admin role functionality without the user being assigned the admin role, you will have a hard time updating your code.

However, if you add a method like this to your user class:

```
public const string ADMIN_ROLE = "ADMIN";
public const string SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE = "SUPERADMIN";

public bool HasAdminAuthority() {
   // Assuming roles are not indexed by name
   foreach (string sRole in this.Roles) {
      switch (sRole.ToUpper()) {
          case ADMIN_ROLE:
             return true;

          case SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE:
             return true;

      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Another useful method to add is something like:

```
public bool IsInRole(string sRoleToFind) {

   foreach (string sRole in this.Roles) {
      if (sRoleToFind.Equals(sRole, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then you can use one of these methods in your UI logic to control the behavior (I would strongly recommend the first one).

Also note that in both of the above examples, if the roles in the user are in dictionaries, for example, the loops can be replaced by `.ContainsKey` method calls on the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LoginView` Control.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lgvAdmins" runat="server">
     <asp:rolegroup roles="Administrators">
          <contenttemplate>
               ...controls...
          </contenttemplate>
     </rolegroup>
     <asp:rolegroup roles="Users">
          <contenttemplate>
               ...controls...
          </contenttemplate>
     </rolegroup>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I think you need to enable the `RoleManager` in your web.config though. You can also specify controls for anonymous and other normal logged-in users. Or you could use the Application_BeginRequest to get the user's roles at that point.